# Do you know what the name Edja means and is it commonly associated with a certain Hebrew name?

Tags: hebrew, names, gravestone-inscription

My family is trying to figure out some details for my grandmother's headstone.

Her Hebrew name is forgotten, she went by Edith for as long as I've known her but her Polish name was Edja. I can't find a translation of it and we're hoping that maybe if it is commonly paired with a Hebrew name it might trigger a memory of her Hebrew name.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. I'm not sure that the question, as currently worded, is on topic (and I have voted to close it accordingly). You can [edit] it to make it more explicitly about Judaism.

Comment: This might help a bit: https://www.geni.com/search?search_type=people&names=edja I'm noticing Edja Esther and Edja Ettel... Are you sure she had a separate Hebrew/Yiddish name?

Comment: @alex Isn't it a tradition in Judaism to have a person's Hebrew name on their headstone? Not sure why the vtc?

Comment: Etye is a known diminutive form of Esther (similar to Etta/Etele), attested at least as early as 18th century Eastern Europe/Russia. Alternatively, Эде appears in Russian name lists, related to Eydl.

Comment: Idit is the Hebrew form of Edith

Comment: @Loewian unknown if she had a Hebrew name.

Comment: I'm not sure that there's much need to try and find out if she did then since it's at best unclear if an unused name has any meaning in Judaism.  I believe Rav Yaakov Kamenetsky advised giving only one name to girls since e.g. an unused middle name would only create ambiguities regarding legal documents, such as get or ketubah. (Boys' Hebrew middle names would still be continuously used when they were called to the Torah.) Perhaps worth asking your rabbi.

Comment: @Loewian Thank you for the insight.